# Emoji appears as black diamond when output from mid function

Tags: asp-classic

I have a very simple Classic ASP page here:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%
response.codepage = 65001
response.charset = "UTF-8"
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>testing 123</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <%
        my_string = "str "
        my_string_len = len(my_string)

        response.write "<hr>my_string: " & my_string & "<hr>" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
        response.write "<hr>my_string_len: " & my_string_len & "<hr>" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf

        for i = 1 to len(my_string)
            c = mid(my_string, i, 1)
            response.write "CHAR: " & ASC(c) & " = " & c  & "<br>" & vbcrlf
        next
        %>

    </body>

</html>
```

This appears when I run the page:

```
my_string: str 
my_string_len: 6
CHAR: 115 = s
CHAR: 116 = t
CHAR: 114 = r
CHAR: 32 =
CHAR: 15 = �
CHAR: 15 = �
```

I want to be able to split `my_string` into its constituent letters.

The test confirms that the ASP page can display native emoji characters, since the  character renders correctly when I response.write `my_string`.

However, when the `mid()` function splits out the string, the emoji is split out into two black diamonds.

I presume that's because the emoji isn't a single character long, since the string `str`  has a length of 6 rather than 5 characters.

I wondered if there is any way to be able to split out the string, in a way that emoji characters are still rendered correctly?

Comment: You need to use `MidB()` and select multiple bytes that make up the emoji.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are saving the ASP file in UTF-8 format because this is how IIS determines the data type (ASCII / UTF-8 or otherwise) inside the file. As emoji characters are double byte and text functions need to know to process using double bytes.

Many older ASP files were created using older versions of IDE's that might have saved the files in ASCII.